# PayPal payflowpro error 11581 Profile description is invalid

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

We had paypal setup all working for PayPal API and Payflow pro then we had to change from a Australian account to a UK account. But now the Pro side gives this error response. We've got limited access to the paypal account it self.

> Partner: xxxxxxx Merchant Login(Vender): xxxxxxxxxxxx User: xxxxxxxxx
>   Password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Host Address :payflowpro.paypal.com Host
>   port=443

This is the request we are sending to PayPal:

> PARTNER=xxxxxxxx&VENDOR=xxxxxxx&USER=xxxxxx&PWD=xxxx&TENDER=C&TRXTYPE=R&ACTION=A&ACCT=xxxxXXXXXXXXxxxx&EXPDATE=xxxx&COMMENT1[16]=Regstration
>   - FS&START=02062014&TERM=0&CVV2=xxx&AMT=35.00&PAYPERIOD=MONT&MAXFAILPAYMENTS=0&RETRYNUMDAYS=2&PROFILENAME[14]=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&COMPANYNAME[2]=FS&NAME[12]=xxxx
>   xxxxxx&FIRSTNAME[6]=xxxxxx&LASTNAME[5]=xxxxx&PHONENUM=xx12345678&EMAIL[24]=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&STREET[15]=xxxxxxxx
>   Street&CITY[7]=xxxxxxx&STATE[3]=NSW&ZIP=xxxx&COUNTRY=AU&OPTIONALTRX=S&OPTIONALTRXAMT=35.00

We are getting the following error response from PayPal:

> RESULT=1000&RESPMSG=Generic processor error: 11581-Profile description
>   is invalid

Google has not really helped. I am hoping a few smart SO guys can assist.

Thank you,
Warren.

Comment: I don't see the profile description included in your request..??

Comment: Hi Andrew, do you mean the &DESC=value description?

Comment: Yes.  Have you tried adding that?

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew. Seems we did not use the DESC field for the AU merchants. But the PayPal UK requires it. Maybe a API version change. Thank you so much.